# WIX install default feature not installed

Tags: wix

I am very new to WIX installer, I have the following feature:

```
<Feature Id="F_MyFeature" Title="My Feature" TypicalDefault="install" Level="1" Display="expand" >
```

Obviously it shows in the feature list as "Will be installed on local hard drive"

I want this feature to show the "X" on it and not to be installed by default, how do I do that ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Features are marked for installation only if their **Level** is lower than [INSTALLLEVEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property value. Most installers have a low INSTALLLEVEL, for example 4 or 1000.

So to make your feature not installed by default (with an X next to it), simply set it's **Level** to a very high value. For example [32767](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
<Feature Id="F_MyFeature" Title="My Feature" TypicalDefault="install" Level="32767" Display="expand" >
```